# Installed new Wildcard certificates on my server, but still appear as expired on browser

Tags: tls, certificates, linux, apache

I have bought new WILDCARD certificates (*.mydomain.com) for my servers.

I was able to install successfully on one server. So, I know the files are correct and I was able to verify their validity.

My servers are running Apache2 on Ubuntu 10 and 12-

I have stored away the old certificates and install the new ones in a new folder, then edited the corresponding configuration file to point to the new certificates.

Restarted apache:

```
$ apache2ctl restart
```

And browsed to the page that should be secured.

I am still getting that my certificates have expired. I have even rebooted the machine to make sure. So, I am guessing that either my certificates are cached on the servers side or the client side ...

As this is new to me, any help is appreciated.

Here the log I get after a reboot

```
[Mon Dec 09 15:05:39 2013] [info] Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server
[Mon Dec 09 15:05:39 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(470): unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[Mon Dec 09 15:05:39 2013] [info] Configuring server for SSL protocol
[Mon Dec 09 15:05:39 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(465): Creating new SSL context (protocols: SSLv3, TLSv1)
[Mon Dec 09 15:05:39 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(613): Configuring client authentication
[Mon Dec 09 15:05:39 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(1208): CA certificate: /C=US/O=Register.com/CN=Register.com CA SSL Services (OV)
[Mon Dec 09 15:05:39 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(1208): CA certificate: /C=US/ST=UT/L=Salt Lake City/O=The USERTRUST Network/OU=http://www.usertrust.com/CN=UTN-USERFirst-Hardware
[Mon Dec 09 15:05:39 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(1208): CA certificate: /C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
[Mon Dec 09 15:05:39 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(676): Configuring permitted SSL ciphers [HIGH:MEDIUM:!ADH:!MD5]
[Mon Dec 09 15:05:39 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(420): Configuring TLS extension handling
[Mon Dec 09 15:05:39 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(807): Configuring RSA server certificate
[Mon Dec 09 15:05:39 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(846): Configuring RSA server private key
[Mon Dec 09 15:05:39 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1818): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 7618 for worker http://localhost/
[Mon Dec 09 15:05:39 2013] [debug] proxy_util.c(1934): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 7618 for (localhost)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I had also node.js instance running on the server.

That node HTTPS server was also using the certificates but since I was only restarting Apache, the new certificates where not taken into account.

Only after a reboot I noticed that there was that node.js server and found where to configure it properly to use the new certificates.

There was no cache whatsoever to worry about.

Comment: You might want to ***accept*** your own answer, so that the question doesn't remain in "open" status.